# How to read line-by-line from a TcpStream?

Tags: tcp, stream, rust

I'm following the *Make a simple TCP server* example in the nightly docs. I've connected via telnet and I'd like to see data sent line by line. Right now I'm `read_to_string` and I only get data when I close the telnet connection. I'd like to be able to read each line at the server after the user in the telnet session hits enter.

Comment: Have a look at BufferedReader.

Comment: Thank you @Levans, I was able to do what I wanted to with the BufferedReader.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what I came up after reading the docs for BufferedReader.

```
fn handle_client(mut stream: TcpStream) {
    let wresult = stream.write_line("Welcome.");
    match wresult {
        Err(e) => {
            println!("error writing: {}", e);
        }
        _ => {}
    }
    let mut reader = BufferedReader::new(stream);

    loop {
        let result = reader.read_line();
        match result {
            Ok(data) => {
                println!("{}", data.as_slice().trim());
            }
            Err(e) => {
                println!("error reading: {}", e);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: `BufferedReader` was renamed to [`BufReader`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html) before Rust's first stable release.